# Как то и как-то

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

После обобщающего слова перед однородными членами иногда употребляется сочетание КАК ТО. Вот цитата из ПАС **Лопатина**:

При обобщающих словах могут быть уточняющие слова... **например, как то, а именно,** перед которыми ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие. Слова **как например, как то** употребляются для пояснения предшествующих слов, слова **а именно** — для указания на исчерпывающий характер последующего перечисления...

*Катя... исследовала сарай, обнаружив там, кроме баллона и плитки, еще массу полезных вещей, **как то**: две низенькие зеленые скамейки, садовый столик, гамак, лопаты, грабли* (Степ.)

В последнее время даже в учебниках (!) вижу после обобщающего слова перед однородными членами КАК-ТО, через дефис, как будто это наречие! В кабинет русского языка пришли таблицы, и на них- КАК-ТО! Более того, в **"Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке" Розенталя** нахожу  информацию  об обобщающих словах, но уже с КАК-ТО! И пример:*"Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, **как-то**: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, - есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие, о котором, может быть, и не знают многие городские люди". (Солоухин)*

Я **категорически против дефиса**, ибо ТО перед однородными членами - это, по сути, указательное местоимение (ср.: как ЭТО). И ударение падает именно на ТО.

***Спрашиваю коллег и не только: как быть, что с этим делать, что говорить  детям? Как то или как-то?***

Comment: В учебнике Н.Г. Гольцовой (10-11 классы,М., "Русское слово", 2017) КАК ТО при однородных членах - отдельно! Стр.60, часть 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте, Катя! Спасибо за вопрос, если честно, не вычитывала досконально Лопатина, и в подобном случае написала бы через дефис. Потому что именно так и рекомендовалось писать! Сравнила то, что было под рукой. (Автор, книга, часть речи, написание)

Розенталь - все - часть речи не определяет - через дефис (в параграфе про однородные члены и в параграфе про написание частиц)

Лопатин - ПАС - уточняющее слово (в параграфе про однородные члены, в орфографической части упоминания нет) - раздельно.

Греков, Чешко Пособие для старших классов  2004 год - союз - через дефис

Хлебинская Русский язык 11 класс 2006 год- часть речи не указывает - дефис

Львов РУсский язык 8 класс (настоятельно рекомендован для подготовки к ГИА, у нас все дети города по этому учебнику занимаются) - 2010 - названо вводным словом - пишет через дефис.

В словарях, которые есть на "Грамоте" - союз - раздельно.

Вот такая история. Я привыкла доверять академическим справочникам и должна выбрать раздельное написание. Авторы учебников, видно, не доверяют. Главный вопрос - что говорить детям? А так и рассказывайте, как есть. Обосновывайте свою точку зрения. 
Кстати, за раздельное написание говорит и ударение "кАк тО" . А меня интересует и морфологическая характеристика этого слова. Тут тоже нет единого мнения.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Лара! Камень с души. Так и буду поступать.    
Вы умница, столько всего пересмотрели! Но, я думаю, Вы не пожалели об этом.)))Меня тоже интересует морфологическая характеристика этого слова. Почти уверена, что ТО - местоимение, а как - сравнительный союз. А вот что они представляют собой вкупе - вопрос №2. Додумаем.

Comment: Не пожалела. Но не нравится мне ситуация в целом. То ли справочник Лопатина - не истина в последней инстанции, то ли авторы учебников так халатно относятся к своей работе (но нет, учебник Хлебинской - добротно сделан, как и проверенный временем Греков -Чешко, вот Львов грешит неоднозначностью подачи материала. Я считаю, что орфографическое написание слов должно быть однозначно закреплено и иметь силу закона. Кстати, в одной из статей Лопатин сказал, что его справочник не рассчитан на школьников.

Comment: И мне не нравится ситуация. Я тоже подумала, что авторы учебников не совсем внимательны. Находила в современных учебниках недочёты и ошибки не раз. (Согласна с Вашей оценкой учебников Хлебинской и пособия Грекова,Чешко.) Обратила внимание, что дефис "фигурирует" в "двухтысячных" изданиях. Не было раньше такой беды!

Comment: Конкретно дефис в "как-тО" был всегда. Мне кажется, авторы просто не согласны с нововведением.

Answer (score 3):

Подробнее здесь: [Чем "как-то" отличается от "как то"](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.52)

Comment: Серж, я Вас от души благодарю! Вы даже не представляете, как помогли мне! Оказывается, не я одна бью тревогу. Спа-си-бо!

Comment: Не за что. Вот только удивляет одно: почему в современных учебниках, автор которых И. Б. Голуб, "как то",  перед перечислением рекомендуется писать через дефис. Неужели такой авторитетный лингвист не видит разницы между как-то и как то?

Comment: Серж, а может быть они считают, что союз "как-то" пишется через дефис, как и местоимение. (К примеру, предлоги имеют три формы написания, в том числе дефисную). Ведь раздельное написание "как то" - это тоже прецедент   для частицы ТО (не самостоятельной, а  отнесенной к конкретному слову).

Comment: София, они считают,что "то" - это частица в разных значениях. Но как указывается в статье ( пройдитесь по ссылке), даже при жизненных изданиях Розенталя, Голуб, рекомендовалось писать как-то и как то соответственно. Однако в некоторых изданиях Розенталя, Голуб ( в том числе в той красной книжке "Домашний репетитор", вы, наверное, знаете) рекомендуется писать как-то во всех значениях.Мне кажется,это уже издатели искажают правила. Но тогда почему об этом молчит сама Голуб?

Answer (score 2):

> > > Катя... исследовала сарай, обнаружив там, кроме баллона и плитки, еще массу полезных вещей, как то: две низенькие зеленые скамейки, садовый столик, гамак, лопаты, грабли (Степ.)

Вообще нет смысла писать в этом предложении *как то*. Нужно сразу после слова *вещей* поставить двоеточие и начать перечиление. Остальное все от лукавого.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже стараюсь включать логику, когда пытаюсь объяснить молодежи правописание тех или иных слов, поэтому полностью согласен с Вами, что дефис в КАК ТО в указанном контексте неуместен. Но что поделаешь? Нам часто приходится запоминать правописание слов, в том числе с дефисом. Почему "на-гора" так пишется? Почему "точка в точку", но "точь-в-точь"? Да не почему.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит брать в качестве примеров фразы из произведений каких-либо авторов. Они часто "мудрят". В нашем случае или "При обобщающих словах могут быть уточняющие слова... например, как то, а именно, перед которыми ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие. Слова как например, как то употребляются для пояснения предшествующих слов, слова а именно — для указания на исчерпывающий характер последующего перечисления..." или "Суффиксы …-ТО, …-ЛИБО, …- НИБУДЬ пишутся с наречиями через дефис "

Answer (score 0):

Школа отстает от науки, это факт. Сами авторы учебников больше методисты, чем ученые, которые обладают фундаментальными знаниями и следят за последними достижениями науки. Методист решает вопрос, как рассказать детям о чем-то, пользуется часто устаревшими сведениями и не очень глубоко копает. К тому же, учебник всегда упрощает материал, он дает основы науки, но не всю ее полноту. Как редактор всегда пользуюсь словарем-справочником В.В. Лопатина - главного научного сотрудника Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН, председателя Орфографической комиссии РАН, наиболее полная и "свежая" информация у него.