# Как правильно пишется союз перед перечислением: как то или как-то?

Tags: союзы, слитно-дефис

**Диалог:**

– *Кстати, "как то" по нынешним нормам пишется раздельно в значении союза. Непонятно, почему Грамота не исправит это. Есть старые нормы, которых хочется придерживаться и сейчас, но не в этом случае — плохо понимаю, зачем вообще писали через дефис.*

– *Точно, спасибо, я знаю, машинально переписала.*

**Из Справочника по пунктуации:**

**КАК ТО, союз** (перед перечислением)
Перед союзом «как то», выступающим между обобщающим словом и рядом однородных членов, ставится запятая, а после него – двоеточие. Для школьников были закуплены канцтовары, как то: ручки, тетради, клей.

@ Орфографический комментарий. В отличие от наречия «как-то» союз «как то» (перед перечислением) пишется раздельно. **Дефисное написание союза (рекомендовавшееся ранее) не соответствует современной норме письма.** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_354&layout=item

**А что всё-таки случилось с орфографическими нормами и когда это произошло?** Вот **Правила 1956 года** (культурный памятник эпохи): *Острогою бьется крупная рыба, **как-то**: щуки, сомы, жерехи, судаки* (С. Аксаков).

Академики составляли (Виноградов, Щерба, Бархударов и др.).

**Вот Справочник Розенталя,** по которому мы работаем (2005 год, кажется): 2. Если после обобщающего слова (словосочетания) стоят слова ***как-то***, а именно, например, то есть, то перед ними ставится запятая, а после них — двоеточие.

Так когда же произошло столь знаменательное событие, как изменение нормы? Почему 60 лет она была действующей, а потом перестала соответствовать.

И я вроде с этим согласилась (на все сто!), а почему? **Машинально**, то есть на автомате: не думая, не сомневаясь, всё принимая на веру. **Наверное, это был коллективный гипноз**.

А как вы объясняете раздельное написание ***как то***? Пожалуйста, убедите меня, а то мне хочется встать на сторону академиков и Розенталя, а не новых реформаторов. **Или среди них тоже были академики?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 10.05.2020**

1) Надо полагать, что раздельное написание слова было введено в 2005 году. РАН довольно свободно распоряжается словарем русского языка, что нельзя сказать о правилах (для этого нужна реформа). Однако **изменение формы** написания существующего слова – это всё-таки похоже **на реформирование** и шаг довольно ответственный.

[https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/350/как_то](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/350/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%82%D0%BE)

**Орфографический комментарий.** Союз «как то» не следует путать с местоименным наречием «как-то», которое пишется через дефис. В словарях и справочниках до последнего времени союз «как то» (перед перечислением) рекомендовалось писать через дефис. Однако дефисное написание не соответствует современной норме письма. Раздельное написание союза «как то» зафиксировано **«Русским орфографическим словарем» РАН (М., 2005), «Словарем наречий и служебных слов русского языка» (М., 2005)** и другими справочными изданиями.

2) И остается вопрос **о произношении**: изменилось ли ударение, как произносили раньше, как произносят сейчас. При дефисном написании союз ***кАк-то,*** скорее всего, произносился так же, как наречие ***кАк-то***.   Чтобы поставить новое ударение, надо реально его слышать в речи. Это могут быть **аудиокниги, литературные записи, фильмы**. Нарисовать ударение на бумаге легко, но действительно ли теперь в  ***как тО*** ударным является местоимение?

Comment: Sharon, а куда раньше падало ударение в этом союзе? Сейчас на "то". Мне сложно себе представить дефисное написание с таким ударением. Может, изменилось ударение и пришлось убрать дефис? Мне намного больше нравится раздельное написание.

Comment: А где это узнать? Наверное, по-разному произносят, возможно, норма изменилась или меняется.  Но тогда мне хотелось бы это объяснение прочитать в Справочнике или еще где-то. Вы, конечно, близки к истине (я догадываюсь почему), но у большинства пользователей другая логика. Вот мне и  хотелось бы узнать какая.  Услышать, например,  такой текст: старая орфографическая норма устарела, так как...  Или мы недостойны таких подробностей?

Comment: @Sharon, на Gramma.ru есть интересная статья про союз как то. Прочитайте. Думаю,все вопросы решатся. К сожалению, нет на данный момент возможности дать вам ссылку.

Comment: Серж, спасибо, я посмотрела, вот эта статья http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.52  Но я добавлю свой ответ, так как не все вопросы для меня решились. Думаю, что наличие разных мнений никогда не помешает.

Comment: Я задавала такой же вопрос в 2012 году: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: Екатерина, большое спасибо за ссылку, я  не видела вопроса. Впрочем, нисколько не жалею. Пусть будет больше разного материала.

Comment: Давайте уберём мою запятую, раз она неправильная. Я курсив сделал, потому что это примеры слов. Вместо кавычек.

Comment: Ваше желание исполнено. Надеюсь, вы не обиделись за цитату, ведь персонажи не названы по именам. К тому же вы первым высказали мнение, которое участники форума посчитали единственно правильным. Удачи вам и праздничного настроения.

Comment: Вам тоже! С Днём Победы!

Comment: @grizzly и Sharon, что касается ударения, мне попалось вот что. В фильме 1968 года "Семь стариков и одна девушка" Папанов делает ударение на "как": *Если вас уволят по статье КЗоТ, к**а**к(-)то: опоздание, пьянство, мелкое хулиганство, без согласия месткома, а местком на это согласия не даст, ибо...* (24:39)

Comment: Спасибо, Артем! Оказывается, произношение можно проверять по фильмам. Это идея!

Comment: Да, конечно! Я старые фильмы люблю и за это в том числе. ;)

Comment: Надеюсь, Alex_ander, вы не придерётесь. Имел в виду, что люблю вообще много за что (это подразумевалось) и за это в частности или в том числе.

Answer (score 7):

Странно. Не знаю почему, но, слава богу, мне не попадалось написание через дефис ***как-то*** перед перечислением. Может, просто не обращал внимания? Не думаю — моя педантичная натура сразу бы воспротивилась!

О том, что была норма с дефисом, узнал не из этого вопроса, а немного раньше. Точно так же, как и собеседник в диалоге, абсолютно не «понимаю, зачем вообще писали через дефис». Ведь кажется совершенно логичным, что ***как-то*** — это наречие, а ***как то*** — союз, этакий симбиоз союза с указательным местоимением (я не о том случае, о котором говорит Грамота: «**! Не смешивать**»). Последнее сродни сравнительному обороту с ***как***, во многих случаях его можно смело заменить на ***таких как*** или ***как, например***.

Очень рад, что сейчас это "недоразумение" разрешилось.

Comment: Очень рады? Ну что ж,  как сказал поэт, "шпага для дуэли, меч для битвы". Значит,  не попадалось? Так это мы сейчас поправим, вам стоит только заглянуть  в Справочник Розенталя (онлайн). Видите дефисное написание, обратите внимание. Так откуда там дефис, может, академики это знали?  Да теперь у них не спросишь... А вот грамматическая форма «как то» не кажется вам странной? Это тоже устойчивое (застывшее)  выражение, которое не соответствует истинной грамматике предложения.

Comment: Да и  различение не состоялось. Как теперь союзное "как то" отличать от "натурального" грамматического «как то»? Различили одно, но смешали другое.  Мы очень любим ломать то, что не понимаем. Так вы можете объяснить, почему  там 60 лет писался дефис, версии есть?  Может, надо начинать с определения того, что  вообще в  правописании обозначает дефисная форма. Имеет она какое-то обобщенное значение, когда мы ее применяем, когда переходим от раздельного письма к дефисному?

Comment: Получается, что 60 лет назад тоже сломали? А сейчас вернулись к старому? Пусть грамматически это выглядит странным. Но вернулись-то к **устойчивому** выражению, которое мне не очень нравится (может, оно вообще устаревает), но, на мой взгляд, больше подходит к таким случаям в отличие от дефисного.

Comment: Устойчивым этот союз будет при любом написании, союз КАК в его составе значения сравнения не имеет. А что мы 60 лет назад сломали? У Аксакова (изд. 1858 года) пишется "как-то". В 1956 году просто фиксировали существующую традицию, посчитав ее правильной. Вспомним, что некоторые формы письма тогда были изменены. А мнения надо как-то обосновывать, не всегда достаточно сказать: я так думаю. И еще вопрос; вы УДАРЕНИЕ куда ставите?

Comment: Я не сказал, что составной союз идентичен сравнению, сказал "сродни". Вы правы, обоснования не достаточно, это, скорее, идет от ощущения языка, что _как-то_ -  наречие, подразумевающее неопределенность, а _как то_ - определяет _то_, что последует за ним. И про смешение:  после "натурального" _как то_ не может ставиться двоеточие. Никакого смешения. Ударение здесь не ярко выражено, но уж точно не на _как_. Два слова произношу с еле заметной паузой.

Comment: В _как-то_  последнее "о" произносится неясно, ближе к "а", а в _как то_ явно чувствуется "о".

Comment: В словарной статье на Грамоте ударение поставлено; кАк-то и как тО. Но союз этот типично книжный, в обычной речи он практически не употребляется. Тогда как узнать, какова норма произношения (раньше, теперь). А вы где реально слышали текст с этим союзом? Я, честно говоря, была уверена, что произносится кАк-то, просто это можно было считать с дефисного письма. Ну и теперь, в силу привычки,  мне членение союза на части представляется  неприятным  - как буто что-то цельное распилили пополам.

Comment: Ну вот опять же, речь идет о субъективном восприятии и привычке. Для меня перед перечислением ну никак невозможно прочитать с ударением на КАК , перед двоеточием хочется выделить ТО. Слышать-то слышал, и не раз, а вот где, как же это вспомнить?

Comment: Надо уметь читать дефисное письмо - это всегда слитное произношение с одним ударением. При таком написании должно читаться кАк-то, иначе форму письма изменили бы еще в 1956 году, но она оставалась до 2005 года точно. Где читались такие тексты? В школе, вероятно, где не сильно грамотные учителя стали читать на свой вкус. Возможно, что постепенно эта традиция закрепилась. При чтении как тО получается какое-то кудахтанье, не различимое на слух.  Слово стоит между двумя паузами и по грамматике напоминает уточняющее существительное "кактО": Острогою бьется крУпная рыба, кактО... Ужас!

Comment: Ладно, читайте и пишите как хотите. Для меня картинка более или менее ясная. Ищите там сравнительный союз КАК и местоимение ТО.  А также радуйтесь, что недоразумение разрешилось. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Согласен, что ужас, тем более, что это стих. Да, КАК ТО стоит между паузами, а читается впроброс, "без ударений".

Comment: Спасибо и вам за интересный вопрос. Да чему радоваться? Ну выразил так свое отношение, что такого? Для меня написание через дефис просто было удивительным. Если бы увидел в Розентале, подумал бы что опечатка нерадивых редакторов. Значит, мало читал. А вы напишете свое видение?

Comment: Не поняла, что надо написать.Про ясную картинку? Мне ясно только то, что ничего не ясно. Для реконструкции событий не хватает деталей. Для себя же я уже назначила наказание: за нарушение режима жизни и излишнюю эмоциональность в течение недели на форум не заходить. Вы уж там поработайте за всех.(Мне кажется, что вопросы задаются, а отвечающих осталось очень мало. Как привлечь людей, почему новые участники не появляются или уходят, немного поработав. Проблема.)

Comment: Мне очень нравится, когда вы задаете проблемный вопрос, а потом сами отвечаете.

Comment: Ого, Александр, ваши читатели вас приветствуют, рада за вас.  Хорошо, когда всё ясно, а все недоразумения разрешаются. Интересное словечко... Наверное, оно обозначает недостаток разума у тех, кто писал как-то через дефис.

Comment: Sharon, вы смеетесь? 2 голоса... А вообще, да — это уже не плохо (новые ответы редко получают много голосов). Я улыбаюсь. Ответ я написал по наитию; может, не по правилам. Разве это не имеет права на сущестование? Слово "недоразумение" намеренно написал в кавычках. Вы же хотели, чтобы форум стал чуточку веселее? :)

Comment: Хотела, очень хотела, чтобы стал веселее, а сейчас вообще веселюсь, просто в цирк ходить не надо. Вы уже прочитали мой ответ с дополнением? Кстати, я проголосовала за два ваших других ответа, потому что не хотела голосовать за этот, а как вас еще отблагодарить за ответ. Но здесь вы без голосов уж точно не останетесь.

Comment: Александр, это я был.))

Comment: В диалоге? Конечно, я знаю. Видел, видел.

Answer (score 2):

Интересный и непростой вопрос с этим союзом. Прежде всего, хочу согласится с Sharon, что все подобные изменения в правописании должны быть пояснены и аргументированы. У меня нет качественного ответа на все заданные вопросы, просто приведу часть информации, которую удалось пока раздобыть. Пусть будет такой расширенный комментарий.

Попытаемся проследить историю "как то" по словарям. Здесь нас ожидают сюрпризы. Вот что говорит ["Словарь русского языка XVIII в."](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/)

> **Как-то**
>   3. в знач. союза. Употр. перед сущ., раскрывающим или уточняющим смысл определяемого слова: *а именно*. Прѣсная вода и защита от болотных трав
>   привлекают к нему <озеру> великое множество различных водяных птиц,
>   **как то** уток, чапур, лебедей и диких гусей. Пут. Леп. I 403.
>   Разъяренный отец увѣдомил его о всем, что ни происходило с его
>   дочерью, **как то**: о ея любви в Любочесту, о намѣрении умертвить себя.
>   Розана 51. Страсти суть многоразличны, **как то**: честолюбие, роскошь,
>   гордость, и проч. САР1 III 394. <Танцовщики> танцуют балет, в котором
>   представляют разныя Гимнастическия игры **как-то**: борьбу, кулачный бой,
>   бѣганье и проч. Држ. Соч. IV 150.

В словаре Ожегова, 1960 г., в словарной статье **как-то** выделяется значение частицы, но с тем же ударением на **а**.
В "Грамматическом словаре" А.А. Зализняка (1980 г.) есть только наречие **как-то** с ударением на **а**.

Просили ещё дать ссылку на современных академиков. Хотя А.А. Зализняк покинул нас, я надеюсь, что авторитет его всё ещё достаточно высок. Вот цитата из его статьи в "Успехах математических наук", 2000 г. (критика так называемой "Новой хронологии" А.Т. Фоменко). [Мне лень делать снимок экрана, но я смотрю чёткую скан-копию журнала.]

> Кстати, уже на одном этом примере мы познакомимся сразу с несколькими
>   фундаментальными лингвистическими принципами, которыми пользуются
>   авторы НХ, **как то**: "существенны только согласные"; "на востоке слова
>   читают задом наперед"; "письменная форма слова исходна, устная —
>   вторична" и др.

**Дополнение.**
Этот вопрос уже [рассматривался на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE). Среди ответов (см. ответ Серж) там есть весьма полезная ссылка, в которой имеется вся необходимая информация: [Чем "как-то" отличается от "как то"](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.52). Если коротко: это в самом деле исправленное недоразумение и союз **как то** (с раздельным написанием) приведен среди пояснительных союзов в учебном пособии Д.Э. Рознеталя с соавторами, вышедшем ещё в 1991 г.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да,  Ожегов как-то при перечислении считал частицой. Видимо, этим и оправдывается и дефисное написание у него.

Answer (score 1):

**Зализняк**, конечно, ученый авторитетный, но  пока неясны  мотивы разного написания ***как-то/как то*** в 1980 году и в 2000 году. Придавал ли он этому значение, занимался  ли проблемой напрямую,  принимал ли  непосредственное участие в изменении  письма?

Я же попробую дать **свое видение проблемы**.

**До 1956 года** в русской орфографии было немало парных написаний, которые выбирались авторами произвольно, по своему желанию, поэтому  не удивляет  их наличие в словаре 18 века. Собственно говоря, именно принятые тогда правила утвердили  нормы, которые нужно было  теперь  соблюдать однозначно.

Наречие ***кАк-то***   всем известно, для пользователей это  хорошо узнаваемая фонетическая и графическая форма.  Никто не собирается писать это слово раздельно,  чтобы обозначить его структуру – и так  ясно, что неопределенная частица ***то*** в какой-то мере сохраняет свое указательное значение в тех словах, к которым она присоединяется. Дефисное письмо подсказывает нам **слитное произношение**, при этом **ударение удобно ставить на первом слоге**.

У наречия ***кАк-то***   имеется (или раньше имелся) **синоним** – пояснительный союз ***кАк-то***, стоящий перед перечислением и имеющий значение  «а именно, то есть». Здесь используются те же формы,  что и у наречия (фонетическая и графическая), хорошо знакомые пользователям. Это кого-то удивляет, **разве в русском языке нет синонимов?** Грамматическая роль наречия и союза **ЛЕГКО РАЗЛИЧАЕТСЯ,**  что же еще надо?

Зачем нужно делить союз на части, ведь и  так ясна его исходная структура. **Нет, хочется, разделили, и что имеем?**

**И ударение** перенесли на частицу ***тО***, да только зачем? Всё равно в предложении  слоги  ***как***  и ***то*** произносятся слитно, но только теперь с ударением  на втором слоге, так что образуется странное слово «***кактО***». Стоит оно в позиции между двумя паузами и выглядит **как уточнение**.   Изменили узнаваемую фонетику, графику, изобрели «кактО», обособили. **Ну и как, нравится?**

Вот и пример: *Острогою бьется крУпная рыба, **как тО**: щуки, сомы, жерехи, судаки.* Вы слышите, что получается: рыба, иначе говоря «***кактО***».

**И еще одно достижение.** Нас предупреждают. **Не смешивать** с сочетанием союза и местоимения: «Глаза были синие, ***как то*** небо, а косы светлые, будто она их мыла в золотой воде».  Что ж, хотели дифференцировать (это так важно!), но **одно различили, другое смешали.**

Вот такие у меня мысли, такое видение проблемы. Да, мы не можем изменить орфографию и фонетику этого слова, но должны хотя бы понимать ситуацию и критически оценивать то, что нам предлагается.

Вспомним еще раз Булгакова:  **«А вы соглашались с вашим собеседником? — На все сто!»**

Вот никогда не надо соглашаться "на все сто", разве это неясно (шутка).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Итак, крамольную форму  ***как-то*** все дружно заклеймили еще в 2014 году. По-зор! По-зор! **Как только академики пропустили такое безобразие**! В образовательном процессе главное – это однозначная правильность, **инакомыслие очень вредит детям.**

Но я всё-таки приведу **другой диалог из того времени**:

– Вот только удивляет одно: почему в современных учебниках, автор которых И. Б. Голуб, "как то", перед перечислением рекомендуется писать через дефис. Неужели **такой авторитетный лингвист не видит разницы между как-то и как то?**

– А может быть они считают, что **союз "как-то" пишется через дефис, как и местоимение.**

Comment: Вот чего я действительно не понимаю в реформе 1956: почему **то-есть** в значении союза сделали раздельным, а **как-то** оставили с дефисом. Ради этого пришлось у **как-то** отобрать значение союза и превратить его в частицу. Это действительно выглядит недоразумением.

Comment: Да, прочитал дополнение.Здорово! Пусть академики разбираются! А я, пока они снова не станут писать через дефис, буду радоваться!!!

Comment: @grizzly  А меня это не удивляет.  Зачем "то есть"  писать через дефис, многие союзные соединения пишутся раздельно, здесь сохранена естественная грамматика, ударение на месте (на первом слоге).  А союз и частицы и сейчас не всегда различают, часто говорят частица в значении союза.

Comment: Я удалил свой комментарий. Зря я вчера поддался эмоциям. С уважением (и с праздником! :)

Comment: Спасибо, Вас тоже с праздником. Зато разговор получился откровенный и интересный, как мне так кажется, много материала добавилось.

Answer (score 1):

Это ответ на полученный комментарий от одного из участников. Дословно это прозвучало так:  "**Вы или недостаточно внимательны, или воспринимаете информацию слишком выборочно**".

**Я просмотрела всю информацию, уверяю Вас.**  Давайте считать, что я недостаточно внимательна, всё-таки выборочный подбор — это более серьезный проступок (или неумение работать с информацией).

**Но  вы (я имею в виду  участников форума вообще) ко мне тоже недостаточно внимательны, вы меня не слышите, а тогда и я вас не слышу.** Диалога у нас не получается.  Извините, но мне кажется, что вы ищете не истину, а общее  мнение и те авторитеты, на которые при этом удобно опереться, чтобы одинаково думать.  Что ж, надо порадоваться за вас, ваша точка зрения доставила удовольствие **по меньшей мере десятку наших участников.**  Да что там говорить, рады будут все (исключений не будет).

**О Розентале.** Я не знаю, какие книги Розенталь редактировал сам, в 1991 году ему было это сложно (91 год как-никак). И дело тут не только в здоровье, но и в окружении. Конечно, хочется верить, что все лингвисты — это честные, добрые, умные люди, но так ли это.  **Так ли свободен был в своих решениях наш великий ученый даже в молодые годы, а что уж говорить о последних годах.**  Что позволили, то и сказал, что смог, то и сделал. Не очень легкое было тогда время для развития блистательного таланта,  думаю, что цензура была очень жесткой.  Я часто вижу в текстах его правил **странные несоответствия**,  сам он так не мог написать, всё отредактировали. И очень **многое недосказанного** читается между строк.

И пара слов о многострадальном союзе ***как-то***.  У нас многие памятники  охраняются государством, но только не памятники нашей книжной речи и культуры.  Мы очень любим **реформировать и редактировать свою письменность**, не оставляя камня на камне. Почему  в других странах ничего такого нет, **никто не изменяет английскую или французскую орфографию,** не приводит ее к единообразию.

У этого союза очень маленькое жизненное пространство, **крошечная роль в грамматике, которую ни с чем не спутаешь.**  Он  сугубо книжный и немного архаичный,  в нем есть какая-то  особая художественность и запах времени, **он сам словно памятник старины.**  Но нет, именно он помешал вашему образовательному процессу. И результат:  нет больше союза ***как-то***,  осталась нелепая графика и такое же произношение.

Comment: "Уверяю Вас" — это кому?) Я даже не знаю, как теперь относиться...

Comment: Sharon, как видно из статьи, да и из самих примеров, с этим словом всегда был разнобой.  Он даже в правилах 56 не упоминается. Лингвисты устронили разнобой. Вот и все. Что вас не устроили? Даже рекомендация справочника Розенталя не всегда соблюдалась. И неизвестно: какого мнения был сам Розенталь. Поэтому считать эту рекомендацию абсолютно корректной тоже нельзя.

Comment: Что каксается Ирины Голуб, действительно, в ее пособиях тоже встречается дефисное написание. Голуб жива, но, к сожалению, автор статьи не обратилась к ней. А в соц.сетях ее, к сожалению, нет.

Comment: *Он сугубо книжный и немного архаичный, в нем есть какая-то особая художественность и запах времени, **он сам словно памятник старины.*** Меня бы это тронуло и я подписался бы под этим в случае с другой какой-то особенностью языка (сейчас тоже я задумался, когда это прочитал), но Серж тоже убедителен. Забыл за вопрос проголосовать, стоит того.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, я сейчас еще что-нибудь трогательное напишу, попробую вас разжалобить  (шутка).

Comment: Артем, не знаете, как ко мне относиться или к союзу? Пожалуйста, относитесь к нам обоим хорошо. Серж, у меня бумажная книга 1956 года. Там есть предложение с союзом «как-то», а также союз включен в словарь. А что там с Розенталем, я не знаю. У меня в книге 2005 года в правилах дается предложение с «как-то». Так какие же лингвисты устранили разнобой и когда это случилось? Кто стоит за этой фразой: "Дефисное написание союза (рекомендовавшееся ранее) не соответствует современной норме письма"? И почему до сих пор не исправлена редакция правил Розенталя онлайн?

Comment: Лопатина я плохо прочитала? Признаюсь, я не поклонник его творчества, до сих пор слова «миллионоголосый» простить ему не могу. Сейчас в словаре пишется одна Н, а то было две НН (его достижение). И наш коллектив тогда дружно (или не очень) проголосовал за несомненно правильное НН. Правда, я там нашла такую фразу от читателей: «София, я прислушалась к Вам, как делаю это всегда. С огромным удовольствием читаю Ваши развёрнутые комментарии. Жаль, что нет такого общественного движения, которое бы объединило всех неравнодушных к родному языку»

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26831/Как-правильно-миллионоголосый-или-миллионноголосый И мне тоже жаль, что нет, или, может, кто-нибудь посоветует адресок? Иначе куда же нам, неравнодушным, податься? А вот и он, господин Лопатин, тоже бумажный: «Русское правописание сегодня» 2007 год. Это не правила, а рассуждения о правилах. Свод 1956 года он, разумеется, не читал, но уверяет, что «как-то» там нет. И далее: «Дефисное написание не соответствует его природе составного союза (союз КАК + местоимение ТО)». Ну просто открытие сделал! Так что читала я Лопатина…

Comment: *Артем, не знаете, как ко мне относиться или к союзу?* К союзу, конечно. К вам я отношусь очень хорошо и даже не думаю, что что-то может измениться. Только в лучшую сторону. *Спасибо, Артем, я сейчас еще что-нибудь трогательное напишу, попробую вас разжалобить* — ))))))

Comment: Sharon, у меня есть Орфографический словарь русского языка. Под редакцией С.Г. Бархударова, С.И.Ожегова,  и А.Б.Шапиро.Там только: как-то ( без каких.л. помет).

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за информацию, а какого он года? Я смотрела по словарю, который приложен в Правилам (как часть III).

Comment: Издание 1960года.

Comment: Sharon, а я вас [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448369/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8/448371) спросил.