# Как то / как-то (трудный случай)

Tags: орфография, союзы, раздельно-дефис, обобщающее-слово

Два гиганта говорят разное, поэтому нужна, совы, ваша-с помощь!
[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74#pp74) говорит, что в данном случае мы должны *как-то* с дефисом писать-таки, а [Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113) говорит, что без него. Кому верить?

Пример: *У меня было много котов, **как-то / как то**: чёрный, белый, серый, жёлтый...*

Comment: Совы заметили, что вопрос о **как то / как-то** уже рассматривался на сайте, интенсивно и не единожды. Посмотрите: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be (Как то и как-то).

Comment: Вот еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460656/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%be (Как правильно пишется союз перед перечислением: как то или как-то?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Формант «как то»** назван союзом только **в орфографическом словаре РАН.**  Его нет ни в одном толковом словаре.
2. [В словаре Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/78722):

**КАК-ТО** **4. союз.** То же, что ***а именно***. Все предприятия, ***как-то:*** строительные, текстильные, полиграфические работают нормально.

Итак, у Ожегова тоже был союз "как-то", теперь же его просто преобразовали в союз "как то".

3. Почему слово «как-то» стоит **перед перечислением**? Это можно объяснить значением указательной частицы ***ТО***:

**Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова**

**-ТО, частица.**  3. Употр. после местоименных слов вместо конкретного указания на **перечисляемые** предметы, действия или признаки. Рассказывает: был там-то и там-то, делал то-то и то-то, встречался с теми-то.

4. "Как-то" с дефисным написанием можно рассматривать как **особое слово** – предупреждении о перечислении. А **что за грамматика** у союзного сочетания "как то"? Загадка для пользователей?
5. **Кстати, о фонетике.**

Союз "***кАк-то***" – одно фонетическое слово, ударение на "как".

Союз "***как тО*** – ударение на "то" в конце фразы перед двоеточием.

Воспринимается некорректно. Думаю, что писатели-классики и академики в 1956 году это тоже **учитывали**.

**Вывод.** Более корректной выглядит форма ***«как-то»*** в правилах Розенталя, но решение словаря РАН (и ПАС под ред. Лопатина) является **обязательным для исполнения.**

Поэтому **пишем**: *У меня было много котов, **как тО**: чёрный, белый, серый, жёлтый...*

А вот **как произносим?**  Если с ударением на "как", то это соответствует **дефисному** написанию.

Answer (score 4):

В настоящее время пишем без дефиса.

> **КАК ТО,** *союз* (перед перечислением)
> <...>
> @ Орфографический комментарий. В отличие от наречия «как-то» союз «как то» (перед перечислением) пишется раздельно. Дефисное написание союза (рекомендовавшееся ранее) не соответствует современной норме письма.
> [[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_354&layout=item)]

Большое обсуждение было здесь:
[Как правильно пишется союз перед перечислением: как то или как-то?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460656/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE)

Comment: Александр, а есть ли что-нибудь новое по этой теме, что еще не обсуждали?  Ведь две формы письма – это не только изменение традиционного написания,  но и новый смысл тоже. И вот до конца не очень понятно, чем по смыслу отличаются "как-то" и "как то". Спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну... Раз вопрос поддержали... Поддержим и ответ. Хотя, если я правильно понимаю, *в товарищах согласья нет*. Похоже — баталии еще впереди. P. S. О правке: слеш, мне думается, надо писать с пробелами.

Comment: Sharon, по смыслу "как-то" сюда не подходит, это наречие. А при раздельном написании всё встало на свои места: "то" теоретически можно убрать, останется "как", и смысл будет такой: "как, например", "такие как".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: Если только теоретически убрать одно и подставить другое, то да, наверное) Но мы-то это практически видим, поэтому и спрашиваем. Опять же о чем думали наши писатели и академики-гиганты раньше? Неужели не замечали, что "по смыслу "как-то" сюда не подходит, это наречие."   Меня вот этот вопрос особенно волнует. Спасибо. Я, конечно, вас "напрягаю" не по делу,  но вы как бы оказались на линии фронта (шутка).

Comment: И еще одна деталь, это словари. У Ожегова для "как-то" есть значение "То же, что "а именно": https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/78722 У Кузнецова этого нет, но КАК ТО (союз) указан только в орфографическом словаре. Насколько корректна такая грамматика, когда это внесено – все неясно. Много вопросов (они для всех), и я надеюсь на НОВЫЕ ответы наших участников по этой теме. Голос от меня за полезную информацию.

Comment: @Sharon  Спасибо, Sharon! Ну, Ожегов уже тоже относительно давнишний.

Answer (score 1):

**К ИСТОРИИ СОЮЗА «КАК ТО».**

Из ответа **Sharon** в этой теме:

> **Формант «как то»** назван союзом только **в орфографическом словаре РАН.**

Не только. Задолго до выхода орфографического словаря РАН «как то» назывался союзом и в учебнике Розенталя & Co.

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Исправляюсь)

**Как-то**, **то** - частица, а как-то - не союз, а сродни необязательных вводных конструкций или оборотов, можно выкинуть вообще всю конструкцию и ничего особо не меняется, хотя его любили ставить перед перечислением чего-то.

Второе - по-русски прилагательные хорошо бы согласовать с определяемым словом, если это не клички котов:

> У меня было **много котов** (разных цветов), **как-то**: чёрн**ых**, бел**ых**, сер**ых**, жёлт**ых**...

котов - черных(!), а не котов - черный...

Можно выкинуть *как-то* без потери содержания и согласования:

У меня было много котов: чёрных, белых, серых, жёлтых...

Отсутствие как-то никак не отражается на повествовании. *Как-то* выполняет формальную функцию, некоторого логического знака перед двоеточием.

> Всякий родитель должен **воздерживаться** при детях своих не только **от** дел, но и от слов, клонящихся к неправосудию и насильству, **как-то**: бран**и**, клятв**ы**, драк, всякой жестокост**и** и тому подобных поступоков; и не дозволять и тем, которые окружают детей его, давать им такие дурные примеры. Екатерина II. Наказ Комиссии о составлении проекта нового Уложения (1767)

"воздерживаться от - брани", после как-то идет согласование характеристики с определяемым словом.

> Посередине судна на возвышенном несколькими ступенями столбе, или престоле, под балдахином стоял Перунов истукан — бога, производящего все воздушные действия и явления, **как-то**: грома, молнии, облаков, дождя и прочего, держащий в руках блестящий камень, наподобие пылающей молнии. М. Д. Чулков. Пересмешник, или Славенские сказки (1766-1768)

> И как **государыня** сия с самого уже начала прусской войны сделалась **как-то** **нездорова** и подвержена была частым болезненным припадкам и столь сильным.. Болотов.

Ну тут нет двоеточия, однако наличие как-то необязательно: государыня сделалась нездорова. Как-то ~ каким-то образом.

> Сверх того князь Урусов был **как-то** увертливее меня... Он же.

Убираем  *как-то* из контекста, не меняя почти ничего:

Он как-то сумел уладить дело. ~ Он сумел сладить дело.

Зашёл как-то вечерком. ~ Зашёл вечерком.

То есть как-то это какое-то слово связка, необязательное для употребления.

А вот КАК ТО участвует в образовании подчинительных конструкций конструкций, после КАК ТО часто заменимо на *ТАК КАК* или на *ЧТО*/*О ЧёМ*, либо всегда можно расширить до КАК ТО, ЧТО/О ЧЕМ/О ТЕХ и тд:

> **Как то** *(Что)* было не далече, то он пришел ко мне скоро и на вопрос мой об оном пивоваренном дворе рассказал мне сходно, как я о нем от других слышал. Я. П. Шаховской. Воспоминания (1766-1777)

> Ничто полезнее, приятнее и наших трудов достойнее быть не может, **как то, что** теснейшим союзом связано с человеком и предметом своим имеет добродетель, благоденствие и счастие его. Н. И. Новиков. [«О высоком человеческом достоянии»] (1777)

А тут уже есть ",что" с ударением на тО. Или вот:

> Таковая младость едва достигает и до «Утреннего света» в нашей жизни; почему, **как то** (*что*) и со всеми молодыми людьми бывает, мы хотя и великую полагаем надежду на свое прилежание и трудолюбие, однакож не смеем уповать, что по желанию удостоят нас многие своим чтением. Он же.

Хотя вот тут, это выглядит несколько неоднозначно:

> Места около Кизляра не меньше изобилуют птицами, как и зверями разных родов, как то кабанами, оленями, зайцами и пр [очими]. Н. Я. Озерецковский. Дневник (1782)

Но здесь нет двоеточия... но фраза сложная, изобилуют птицами, как и, как то... ошибка?

Или так лучше?

Места около Кизляра не меньше изобилуют птицами, как и зверями разных родов, как то/те(, что) кабаны, олени, зайцы и пр.?

Либо так:

Места около Кизляра не меньше **изобилуют** птицами, как и зверями разных родов, **как-то:** кабанам**и**, оленям**и**, зайцам**и** и пр.

Изобилуют кабанами - согласование => "как-то:"

Резюмируя:

**Как-то - если выкинуть, то на содержании это почти не отражается. Слово употребляемое для перечисления чего-то, "как-то:" + согласование слов с определяемым словом.**

**КАК ТО** - подчинительный союз с часто урезанным ", что", либо "как то" можно заменить на на другой подчинительный союз, часто можно расширить до на **КАК ТО, ЧТО**, либо содержит другие подчинительные конструкции  "как то прежде" = "что прежде" или "как то, о чем" по сути, либо походит на "как те"(множественное то). **Не требует согласования(?) с определяемым словом, не выкидывается(!).**

> Господин *** уверял, что он ничего приятнее не делает, **как то, о чем** его просит Добронрав; что он никогда не позабудет его к себе одолжений... Новиков.

> в наибольшей дружбе с ней пребывающие и коим преимущественно в коммерции Блистательная Порта благоприятствует, **как то** французы и англичане; - если выкидывать, то тут скорее тире надо ставить, потому что прибывающие - (это) французы, *а не пребывающие: французы*. И нет согласования, прибывающие *французами*.

Или вот:

> Что же касается до **потерпевших** от убиения человека, **как-то** дет**ей**, жен**ы**... Радищев.

Не дети и жена, а потерпевших детей и потерпевшей жены, тут кстати тоже есть момент сложный так как "потерпевших", а жены в единственном числе). Был недавно такой вопрос, как согласовывать.

А вот тут:

> ..где сколько **увеселительных** домов, **как-то**: **кофейных**, трактиров, биллиардов, собраний, клобов... Радищев.

Определяемое не *домов*, а ***увеселительных***.

И тут еще интересное:

> От муфтия и прочих **многие дела** по существу своему не долженствуют подлежать решению правительств духовных, **как-то** **— дела до браков**, разводов, другие. Радищев.

Дела - дела, а "до браков, разводов" - согласовано, но *как-то* - потому что перечисление.

*Хотя Новиков немного подгадил, так как перестал ставить дефис в как-то, и не всегда это было уместно:

> Он сочинял много весьма изрядных мелких стихотворений, **как то** элегий, сонеты, оды анакреонтические, эпиграммы и другие стихотворения и случайные стихи, напечатанные в академических и московских сочинениях разных годов. Новиков.

Хотя тут не однозначно, так как нет согласования сочинял элегии, а стихотворений - элегий, скорее всего тут вообще тире нужно?

То есть или:

Он сочинял много весьма изрядных мелких стихотворений, **как-то**: элегии, сонеты, оды..

Или:

Он сочинял много весьма изрядных мелких стихотворений, **как то** - элегий, сонеты, оды..

А вот тут он берёт и ставит двоеточие, но не ставит дефис:

Он перевел также и много других книг, *как то:* «Жизнь Сифа», «Кариту и Полидора», «Сиднея и Силли» и другие некоторые.. Новиков

**Также есть момент, что людей или личностей было не принято перечислять через двоеточие и как-то.

> Здешние тористы **как-то**, Блудов, Дашков и другие... Тургенев.

Вот не мне поправлять Тургенева, но:

Здешние тористы - Блудов, Дашков и другие... (так можно же?)

> 

А после, у Тургенева в том числе, создается словечко:

> Репнина **как-то** разбили лошади и проломили ему голову — где тонко, тут и рвется! Тургенев.

Как-то = как-то раз, но по прежнему можно выкинуть, без потери содержания.

Пройдусь по Пушкину и Гоголю, ну и Лермонтову:

> Барыни пожилые старались хитро сочетать новый образ одежды с гонимою стариною; чепцы сбивались на соболью шапочку царицы Натальи Кириловны, а робронды и мантильи **как-то** напоминали сарафан и душегрейку. Пушкин.

*Как-то* можно выкинуть.

> Я попробовал обратить ее в балладу — но и баллада **как-то** мне не давалась. Пушкин.

> А все-таки **как-то** весело: видеть перед собою бумажку... Лермонтов.

> Я его не люблю, но мне **как-то** страшно его огорчить!.. Лермонтов.

> Прошлый год, так **как-то** около лета, да чуть ли не на самый день моего патрона...  Гоголь. Вечера на хуторе близ Диканьки: предисловие ко второй части (1831-1832)

> Чорт между тем, когда еще влетал в трубу, **как-то** нечаянно оборотившись, увидел Чуба об руку с кумом, уже далеко от избы. Гоголь.  Ночь перед Рождеством (1831-1832)

Ну и так далее, *так-то* везде можно убрать.

А **так то** - нет:

> Петр с беспокойством ожидал, чем кончатся переговоры, и жалел о том, что флот его не зимовал в Ревеле, **как то** он предполагал. А. С. Пушкин. История Петра: Подготовительные тексты (1835-1836)

> Петр писал Апраксину, что опасается он хитрости шведской: дабы под закрытием флота не учинили они сильного транспорта Либекеру, как то сделали они с датчанами (1700?), в случае, если шведы не сильны, то можно будет напасть на Либекера со всею конницей и с несколько пехоты. Пушкин.

> Как господари мултянский и волошский обещали не только не пойти к Бендерам (**как то** им от Порты приказано)... Пушкин.

> Это я так знаю, **как то, что** ты была сейчас у шинкарки». Гоголь

> Никто не скажет также, чтобы он когда-либо утирал нос полою своего балахона, **как то** делают иные люди его звания; но вынимал из пазухи опрятно сложенный, белый платок, вышитый по всем краям красными нитками, и, исправивши что следует, складывал его снова, по обыкновению, в двенадцатую долю, и прятал в пазуху. Гоголь.

> Поверьте, что история насчет моего носа мне совершенно известна, равно **как то, что** в этом вы есть главные участницы, а не кто другой. Гоголь.

И когда все уже перестают ставить дефис в "как-то:" Пушкин продолжает:

Со времен Петра Великого они **были употребляемы** в большой части главных военных действий России, **как-то:** в 1696 под Азов**ом**; в 1701, 1703, 1704 и 1707 **против шведов**; в 1708 году 1225 казак**ов** были опять посланы для усмирения башкирцев; в 1711 году 1500 человек на Кубань; в 1717 году 1500 казаков пошли с князем Бековичем-Черкасским в Хиву; и так далее» (г. Левшин).

Ну и так далее... Мне кажется, логика - верняк!

Comment: Частицу при желании можно выкинуть?   Попробуем:  (1) Он как-то сумел уладить дело.   Он как сумел уладить дело.
(2) Зашёл как-то вечерком. Зашёл как вечерком.

Comment: @Sharon эх, не сработало, а так хотелось, интересно почему?

Comment: Я пока не знаю, надо подумать...

Comment: @Sharon я исправил) получился огонь, но полотенце-таки.

Comment: Класс! Вы похожи на биокомпьютер!  (Это я так восхищение выражаю.) Признайтесь, это так? Информации по теме много, так что не очень просто со совсем разобраться…  P.S.  Хорошо, что вы стали писать в поле ответа, а не в комментариях.

Comment: @Sharon да, у меня тоже бывают такие подозрения. Я просто загружаю в мозг какую-то информацию, ну по минимуму формулирую какие-то вопросы и ставлю ряд задачу, и он выдает что-то, чего я сам не ожидаю. Я не особо понимаю как это работает, но как-то так. Может пишут так много, потому что пытаюсь понять почему и как он так делает.

Comment: @Sharon а, ну еще пытаюсь душу подключать, или как это называется, психе по-гречески. Психе - это такой инструмент, щуп можно сказать, то чем ощущаешь реальность или то что ощущает реальность. А мозг работает на каких-то алгоритмах сравнения, как игры такие детские были, когда две картинки и найди отличия, может как-то так. Душа щупает, находит отличия, мозг анализирует и выдает ответ)

Comment: @Sharon вообще задачи делятся на несколько классов, что ли: есть задачи те, которые знаешь как решать, но надо посчитать. Есть задачки, которые не знаешь как решать, но понятен вопрос. А есть задачульки - когда нет ни вопроса ни ответа, когда вообще не понятно, что это и что с этим делать, к какой области это относится. Обычно учат решать первый класс задач, то есть решать по алгоритму, второй и третий относятся к олимпиадным. А ну есть еще, когда сама задача никак не сформулирована - это отдельная тема. Ну и бывают еще тесты, где надо методом тыка выбрать правильный алгоритм или ответ...

Comment: @Sharon кстати, вот пишем "что ли", дефис не ставим, хотя надо бы, потому что ли не отбрасывается: Это что-ли дерево? Вот, возможно, одна логика - попытаться выкинуть частицу, и в выражениях "как-то:" - это срабатывает, но там и все как-то/как то можно выкинуть. Но забавно, что, если частица не отбрасывается, но можно выкинуть и все выражения, то есть само по себе как-то или что-ли можно вообще убрать из текста как лишние обороты. И дело не в том, что частица не отбрасывается, а что если частицу убрать, слово превращается в полноценный значимый элемент, а с частицей оно есть - но его нет.

Comment: То есть слова с частицами не несут смысловой нагрузки, то есть не играют роли в логических связях, а словосочетания союз+местоимение - несут.

Answer (score 0):

Из статьи на cyberleninka.ru

**ОРФОГРАФИЯ НАРЕЧИЯ КАК-ТО И СОЮЗА КАК ТО
В ИСТОРИИ РУССКОГО ПИСЬМА**:

Проблема разграничения *как-то* и *как то* актуальна сегодня не менее, чем в предшествующие столетия. Так, в статье «Чем "как-то" отличается от "как то"» С.В. Друговейко-Должанская отмечает, что употребление *как то* при перечислении считают ошибкой читатели сайта и учителя в школе, что критики раздельного написания *как то* цитируют справочник Д.Э. Розенталя, правда изданный уже после его смерти, а также «академические правила русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956 года, в которых о правописании *как (то)* отдельно не говорится, однако это слово (в дефисном написании) фигурирует во многих примерах» при перечислении в значении ‘а именно’ (Друговейко-Должанская, 2013]. В конце статьи автор формулирует правило разграничения дефисного и раздельного написаний *как (то)*….

Мы рассмотрим, когда возник феномен *как-то* и *как то* и какова была орфография данных слов на протяжении трех столетий.

<…>

…Наше исследование показало, что наметившаяся в XVIII в. тенденция разграничения орфографии наречия *как-то* и союза *как то*, использующегося при перечислении, в дальнейшем не получила развития. В течение XIX в. закрепляется дефисное написание наречия *как-то*, тогда как правописание союза *как то* получило значительную вариативность с преобладанием дефисных вариантов. Грамматики и словари XIX в. упорно не замечают феномена *как-то* и *как то* и кодифицируют дефисное написание либо не различая данные лексемы, либо имея в виду только наречие. Вместе с тем в узусе дефисные написания союза при перечислении распространяются и становится преобладающими. Я.К. Грот, исследовавший основные проблемы русского письма в историческом аспекте, также не заметил указанного феномена, не описал его и не кодифицировал затем в «Русском правописании». К сожалению, усилия исследователей, пытающихся сегодня разграничить орфографию наречия *как-то* и союза *как то* пока не достигают результата. Об этом можно судить, например, по словарной статье «**КАК-ТО**» в новейшем «Большом академическом словаре русского языка», издающемся с 2004 г. В данной словарной статье *как-то* определяется
как наречие, у которого есть 4 значения. Под пунктом 4 значится: «Употр. при перечислении; соответствует по знач. словам: а именно, например» [БАС, 2007:568].

Вместе с тем современные орфографисты настойчиво предлагают отграничить союз *как то* от наречия…

===

Полностью статью можно прочитать **[здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/orfografiya-narechiya-kak-to-i-soyuza-kak-to-v-istorii-russkogo-pisma/viewer)**.